# Checking two character arrays for equality C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a program that checks to see if a word inputed to a program matches one of the predefined keywords. Input is going to be coming from a text file and the text file will have a single word in it. So far the text file I have just has the word 'frog' which means the program should clearly print 'No Match Found' but it in fact prints 'Match Found' It prints prints 'Match Found' even when the word in the text file is a string of random letters. Here is my code, does anything stand out to you guys? Thanks

```
#define NUM 4
#define SIZE 12

int isAlpha(char);

//Returns 1 if it is an Alphabetical character, 0 if it is not
int isAlpha(char c) {
  return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' || c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}

int main() {
  char message[141];
  int charCount = 0, c = 0, matchCheck = 0;

  char keywords[NUM][SIZE] = {
    "crackerjack",
    "Hey",
    "dog",
    "feet"
  };

  //Removes non alphabetical characters
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF && charCount <= 140) {
    if(isAlpha(c)){
      message[charCount] = c;
      charCount++;
    }
  }

  //checks if message matches keyword
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {

      //Check if current two characters match
      if (message[j] == keywords[i][j]) {
        //Check if the two matched characters are the null terminator character
      if (message[j] == '\0' && keywords[i][j] == '\0') {
          matchCheck = 1;
          break;
      }
    }  
  } 
}


  //prints "Match Found!" if there was a match
  if (matchCheck == 1)
    printf("Match Found!\n");
  else 
    printf("No Match Found\n");

}
```

Comment: You don't need to write `isAlpha`, C already has `isalpha`.

Comment: The main thing that stands out to me is the lack of `strcmp()`

Comment: You never exit your loop when you find non-matching characters. So all you're testing is whether they both end with a null. But why don't you just use `strcmp()`?

Comment: I understand how to use strcmp with 1 dimensional arrays, but I am unsure how I would use it with my 2 dimensional array 'keywords'. Would it be strcmp(message, keywords[j])

Answer (score 0):

I havent programmed in C in a long time, and I dont have a C compiler with me right now. However, I think that there might be a problem with the logic. You need to check for every word individually. I would do somehting like the following for your last section ...

```
matchAnyWord = 0

for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
    matchCheck = 1; 

    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        if (message[j] == '\0' && keywords[i][j] == '\0') break;
        if (message[j] == '\0' && keywords[i][j] != '\0') { matchCheck = 0; break;}
        if (message[j] != '\0' && keywords[i][j] == '\0') { matchCheck = 0; break;}
        if (message[j] != keywords[i][j] ) { matchCheck = 0; break;}
    } 

    if (matchCheck == 1) {matchAnyWord = 1; break;}
}
```

Note that here we check for the matching of individual words, and introduce a new variable `matchAnyWord` which is actually what you want. I might have errors in the syntax but I think the logic should be more-or-less there.

Cheers!

Also, not sure why the indentation isnt showing up correctly on my browser ...

Comment: Also, remember to add a `'\0'` at the end of the `message`, just to be on the safe side ...